# Is there a browser extension that can record testing scenarios and then create test cases from them?

Tags: automated-testing

I have used selenim IDE but it is not able to check for input errors and stuff like this.
Things I want the browser extension to achieve:

- Check for validation of input scenarios like if the email is incorrect format it should show an error just below the field the tool should verify if the error is visible or not.
- Be able to share the test cases created with my organisation
- Have the ability to switch between different environments and store credentials for each
- Export the test case to rspec

The last point is available in selenium IDE browser extension but I didn't find the other points.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to tell us more about what you are looking for? For instance, do you want to be able to record a scenario that does not generate validation errors and have your tool generate a collection of valid and invalid inputs?

Comment: Also, can you be more detailed as to the meaning of "extension?" Do you mean a browser extension, IDE extension, an extension to some library/app you are using? Nearly all software has the ability to add extensions or plugins and being more detailed can help narrow down advice.

Comment: I have edited my question, let me know if it can be improved better. Thanks for your suggestions!